# Telegram bot doesn't use all methods

Tags: python, telegram-bot

I have tried to make date countdown, but something goes wrong.
So, what we have at that moment:

```
Timer.py
    @bot.message_handler(commands=['countdown'])
    def handle_text(message):
        bot.reply_to(message, constants.countdown)

Constants.py
import datetime
countdown = (datetime.datetime(2017,12,8) - datetime.datetime.now()).days, 'days left'
```

Count down is working, but without message "time left".
If I put "time left" at first position, bot sends only "time left".

Comment: Yeah, and little question: How to make countdown with days and second without macroseconds? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It might be because countdown contains tuple (like `(365, 'days left')`) instead of string. Try:

```
countdown = '%d days left' % (datetime.datetime(2017,12,8) - datetime.datetime.now()).days
```

Comment: "bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, '%d days left' % (datetime.datetime(2017,12,8,8,30) - datetime.datetime.now()))
TypeError: %d format: a number is required, not datetime.timedelta" Sorry, im noob in it

Comment: Looks like you forgot `.days` at the end, should be: `bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, '%d days left' % (datetime.datetime(2017,12,8,8,30) - datetime.datetime.now()).days)`

Comment: You are awesome! Thank you!